# Hamiltonian $\mathbb{Z}$-paths in connected countably infinite vertex-transitive graphs

Tags: graph-theory, infinite-combinatorics, hamiltonian-graphs

A simple, undirected graph $G=(V,E)$ is said to be *vertex-transitive* if for all $a,b\in V$ there is a graph isomorphism $\varphi:G\to G$ such that $\varphi(a) = b$.

If $G = (\omega, E)$ is vertex-transitive and connected, is there a bijection $p:\mathbb{Z}\to \omega$ such that $\{p(k), p(k+1)\} \in E$ for all $k\in\mathbb{Z}$?

Comment: If $G$ is a regular tree of degree $d \geq 3$, there's clearly no such $p$, unless I'm missing something.

Comment: By "bijection" did you mean "injection"? In plain language, are you just asking if $G$ contains a two-way infinite path?

Comment: @bof Thanks for your question for clarification. I am asking whether there is a two-way infinite path covering all vertices - hence bijection

Comment: In that case your question is answered by the comment of @IlkkaTörmä

Comment: Is the version with "injection" instead of "bijection" more interesting?

Comment: @IlkkaTörmä could you put your comment into an answer so we can close this thread?

Comment: @DominicvanderZypen Done.

Comment: But if there's such a trivial counterexample, the question is off-topic here.

Comment: With "injection" instead of "bijection" there's an easy affirmative answer. Namely, a graph contains a $\mathbb Z$-path (not necessarily Hamiltonian) if either (1) every vertex has infinite degree, or (2) every vertex has finite degree, and some vertex $v$ is the midpoint of a path of length $2n$ for every $n\in\mathbb N$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If $G$ is a regular tree of degree $d \geq 3$, there's clearly no such $p$.